# Error in Building Android Demo in UBuntu

Tags: java, android, linux, python-2.7, android-studio

I am trying to do the build the android demo described [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android).

And I keep getting variants of the error below. I have tried changing api-levels as well as manually copying some files into folders.

How to resolve the error? THanks in advance.

```
my@my:~/tensorflow$ bazel build //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo
WARNING: Bazel Android NDK crosstools are based on Android NDK revision 11. The revision of the Android NDK given in android_ndk_repository rule 'androidndk' is '12.1.2977051'.
WARNING: /home/my/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:646:12: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import '//tensorflow/core/debug:debug_graph_utils.cc' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there.
WARNING: /home/my/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:646:12: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import '//tensorflow/core/debug:debug_graph_utils.h' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there.
WARNING: /home/my/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:646:12: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import '//tensorflow/core/kernels:avgpooling_op.h' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there.
WARNING: /home/my/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:646:12: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import '//tensorflow/core/kernels:bounds_check.h' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there.
WARNING: /home/my/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:646:12: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import '//tensorflow/core/kernels:eigen_activations.h' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there.
WARNING: /home/my/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:646:12: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import '//tensorflow/core/kernels:eigen_attention.h' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there.
WARNING: /home/my/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:646:12: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import '//tensorflow/core/kernels:eigen_backward_cuboid_convolutions.h' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there.
WARNING: /home/my/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:646:12: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import '//tensorflow/core/kernels:eigen_backward_spatial_convolutions.h' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there.
WARNING: /home/my/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:646:12: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import '//tensorflow/core/kernels:eigen_cuboid_convolution.h' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there.
WARNING: /home/my/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:646:12: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import '//tensorflow/core/kernels:eigen_patch_3d.h' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there.
WARNING: /home/my/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:646:12: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import '//tensorflow/core/kernels:eigen_pooling.h' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there.
WARNING: /home/my/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:646:12: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import '//tensorflow/core/kernels:eigen_softmax.h' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there.
WARNING: /home/my/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:646:12: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import '//tensorflow/core/kernels:eigen_spatial_convolutions.h' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there.
WARNING: /home/my/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:646:12: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import '//tensorflow/core/kernels:maxpooling_op.h' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there.
WARNING: /home/my/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:646:12: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import '//tensorflow/core/kernels:ops_util.cc' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there.
WARNING: /home/my/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:646:12: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import '//tensorflow/core/kernels:ops_util.h' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there.
WARNING: /home/my/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:646:12: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import '//tensorflow/core/kernels:pooling_ops_common.cc' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there.
WARNING: /home/my/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:646:12: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import '//tensorflow/core/kernels:pooling_ops_common.h' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there.
WARNING: /home/my/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:646:12: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import '//tensorflow/core/util/ctc:ctc_beam_entry.h' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there.
WARNING: /home/my/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:646:12: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import '//tensorflow/core/util/ctc:ctc_beam_scorer.h' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there.
WARNING: /home/my/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:646:12: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import '//tensorflow/core/util/ctc:ctc_beam_search.h' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there.
WARNING: /home/my/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:646:12: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import '//tensorflow/core/util/ctc:ctc_decoder.h' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there.
WARNING: /home/my/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:646:12: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import '//tensorflow/core/util/ctc:ctc_loss_util.h' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there.
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: missing input file '@androidsdk//:platforms/android-23/android.jar'.
ERROR: /home/my/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/android/BUILD:47:1: //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo: missing input file '@androidsdk//:platforms/android-23/android.jar'.
Target //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
ERROR: /home/my/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/android/BUILD:47:1 1 input file(s) do not exist.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.105s, Critical Path: 0.01s
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the necessary SDK platform is actually downloaded. Just installing the SDK manager itself won't do that.

EDIT: If you're using Android Studio, go to Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> SDK Platforms.

From there you can click the check boxes of whichever API level platform you need to download, then be sure to hit apply.

Comment: @FututeShoked I downloaded android studio from the website and then installed it. Anything more to do, plz give some steps. thx.z

Comment: @John77 edited my original answer to include a more detailed explanation